# How to have 2 bootstrap modules? in main.ts

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I need to know how I can enter 2 bootstrap modules

try using this and it doesn't work

**main.ts**

```
import './polyfills';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {NgbdAlertCustomModule} from './app/alert-custom.module'
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import { NgbdAlertSelfclosingModule } from './app/alert-selfclosing.module';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, NgbdAlertSelfclosingModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bootstrap two separate modules to the page you need two separate `bootstrapModule` calls. For example:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(SecondAppModule);
```

However I suspect want you really want to do is include `NgbdAlertSelfclosingModule` in your `AppModule` so you can use its services and components. Try importing it into your `AppModule` like so:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // your declarations
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbdAlertSelfclosingModule
    // all your other imports
  ],
  providers: [
    // your providers
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    // your entryComponents
  ]
})
```